# How to use regular expression validator controller to check the input values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

May i know how to use RegularExpressionValidator controller in Asp.net to check the Input value when is 0 . then show the error message ? Kindly advise

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="Inv_QtyREV" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Not allow input QTY is 0, please check again !!" ValidationExpression="([0])" ControlToValidate= "Inv_Qty" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you only want the text box to enter numbers

use this regular expression

```
^(?=.*[1-9])\d*\.?\d*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

Use `^(?=.*[1-9])\d*\.?\d*$` instead of `([0])`

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="Inv_QtyREV" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Not allow input QTY is 0, please check again !!" ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[1-9])\d*\.?\d*$" ControlToValidate= "Inv_Qty" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="Inv_QtyREV" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Not allow input QTY is 0, please check again !!" ValidationExpression="^[1-9][0-9]*$" ControlToValidate= "Inv_Qty" />
```